# How do I remove the connection of a Project from a repository on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a repository, which I created a Project for under **Projects** to record my progress. But now I want to make the repository public and not include the linked/connected Project when publishing. How do I transfer/remove it from the list?

While it's already private is it possible to remove it from the list so no one will see it when I make the repository public?

- I'm also considering closing the Project but I'm afraid it might still be visible somehow after doing so.
- Delete the Project might be the simplest solution but I also want to keep its content locally. Is it possible to export it into some form of data, e.g. JSON?

[image]